# pyspark VectorUDT to integer or float conversion

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Below is my dataframe

```python
a b c d

1 2 3 [1211]

2 2 4 [1222]

4 5 4 [12322]
```

Here d column is of vector type and was not able to convert directly from vectorUDT to integer below was my code for conversion

```python
newDF = newDF.select(col('d'), 
newDF.d.cast('int').alias('d'))
```

someone please help on same

Comment: what is Predicted_Reservatin_Count_Value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use udf to reserialize the vector and access the values,

```python
>>> from pyspark.sql import function as F
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,Vectors.dense([1211])),(2,2,4,Vectors.dense([1222])),(4,5,4,Vectors.dense([12322]))],['a','b','c','d'])
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+---------+
|  a|  b|  c|        d|
+---+---+---+---------+
|  1|  2|  3| [1211.0]|
|  2|  2|  4| [1222.0]|
|  4|  5|  4|[12322.0]|
+---+---+---+---------+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c: long (nullable = true)
 |-- d: vector (nullable = true)
>>> udf1 = F.udf(lambda x : int(x[0]),IntegerType())
>>> df.select('d',udf1('d').alias('d1')).show()
+---------+-----+
|        d|   d1|
+---------+-----+
| [1211.0]| 1211|
| [1222.0]| 1222|
|[12322.0]|12322|
+---------+-----+

>>> df.select('d',udf1('d').alias('d1')).printSchema()
root
 |-- d: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- d1: integer (nullable = true)
```